# Закрытие меню на мобильном javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть лендинг, на мобильной версии появляется кнопочка при нажатии на которую выпадает меню, но когда я нажимаю на любую ссылку в меню, меню не закрывается, страница переходит к нужному блоку, а меню остаётся, а нужно что бы оно сворачивалось. Уже сил не хватает, никак не могу найти ошибку, помогите пожалуйста

```
  $('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(e) {
        var anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
        }, 1500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.main-menu').addClass('menu-animation');
        } else {
            $('.main-menu').removeClass('menu-animation');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
        }
    });

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top main-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Навигация</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#home"><span>Главная</span> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about"><span>О нас</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#pricing"><span>Клиенту</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#blog"><span>Галерея</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio"><span>Услуги</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact"><span>Связь</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- END CONTAINER -->
</div>
```

Comment: Вместо
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', ...
используйте 
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse', ..

Comment: @Robert Dampilon не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение, проблема была не в js коде а в html.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#home"><span>Главная</span> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#about"><span>О нас</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#pricing"><span>Клиенту</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#blog"><span>Галерея</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#portfolio"><span>Услуги</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#contact"><span>Связь</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

К каждой ссылке добавил

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```